# How do I get two ASP.NET Blazor sites to communicate with each other?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, message-queue

I have a solution that has two Blazor server-side sites, which share a common data project that contains the EF Core `DbContext`. One site is for the company staff to use, where they maintain user accounts and so on, and the other site is for customers, who log in and see their data, make requests, etc.

What I would like is that an action on one site should trigger a notification on the other. For example, let's say a customer requests something, I would like the staff site to show a notification, so they are aware of the request.

From searching around, I can only see two ways of doing this...

1. Have both sites poll the database at regular intervals to see if there is any new data of interest. This can be done, but seems a clunky way to do it. Either we have to poll very regularly, incurring lots of database hits that will mainly be empty, or we poll less often, making the staff wait longer for notications.
2. Use some kind of messaging system. I've looked at some of these, but they all seem very heavyweight (and expensive) and completely overkill for our requirements. We're not anticipating huge numbers of requests, and don't need the resilience that these systems offer. If a notification is missed it's no big deal, it can be picked up later.

Anyone able to comment on these options, or offer a different option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite simply by taking advantage of the fact that Blazor server-side already implements SignalR, so you don't need to do it yourself.

Your question really has two parts, first how do I get one site to communicate with another, and then how do I get the second site to pass the message around?

I'll address the two questions in reverse order, as it's easier to explain that way. I wrote [a blog post](https://www.pixata.co.uk/2021/12/22/mvvm-style-messaging-in-blazor/) a couple of years ago about doing MVVM-style messaging in Blazor. You can read my ramblings if you want the full story, but the simple asnwer is that all you need is the following code (which can all be in the `MessageBroker.cs` file)...

```cs
public static class MessageBroker<T> {
  public static Action<MessageEnvelope<T>>? Receive;

  public static void Send(T entity, MessageTypes messageType) =>
    Receive?.Invoke(new MessageEnvelope<T>(entity, messageType));
}

public enum MessageTypes {
  New,
  Modified,
  Deleted,
}

public record MessageEnvelope<T>(T Entity, MessageTypes MessageType);
```

Then, in the Blazor component that wants to send out a message, you can do the following...

```cs
MessageBroker<Account>.Send(account, MessageTypes.Modified);
```

In this case `account` is an object of type `Account` which has been modified.

In the component that is to receive the message, you do the following...

```cs
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
    MessageBroker<Account>.Receive += async msg => {
      // Do whatever you want with the incoming message...
      // Optionally call StateHasChanged if your UI doesn't update automatically 
      await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    };
  }
```

Here, we hook up to the `Receive` handler. The incoming message is in the `msg` variable, which has two main properties, `Entity`, which is the entity that is being passed in (an `Account` in my sample above) and the `enum` value specifying the state of the entity (new, modified or deleted).

That's all you need! You should actually dispose of the handler when the component life ends, but I'll leave that for you to do.

Note that because the `MessageBroker` class is static, and the two members are static, this will send the message out to any and all clients. If you want to send messages to just the current client, then you'll need to make the class non-static and add non-static versions of `Send` and `Receive`. See the blog post for more details.

As for passing a message between sites, whilst you can do this with a controller, it's much less code to use a minimal API. This can be a single line in `Program.cs`. The site that is sending the message uses `HttpClient` to call the API endpoint, and passes the entity as a parameter. The endpoint on the receiving site just calls `Send` on the message broker to pass the message around the site.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow, that's so simple! Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Use SignalR on the Staff Site.

1. Create a SignalR Hub on the Staff Site "StaffHub".
2. When Staff signs in connect to the Hub from the client.
3. Expose an endpoint in a Controller on the Staff Site, e.g. "NotifyStaff"
4. Inject IHubContext<StaffHub> into the NotifyStaff Controller.
5. Send a message to all Clients on the StaffHub when NotifyStaff is called on the controller.
6. Handle the message on the Staff clients to show the notification.

On the Customer site, when a relevant action is called, use HttpClient to send NotifyStaff request to Staff site.

Alternatively, use a message queue (e.g. RabbitMQ).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I only ever thought of using SignalR inside the one app, clever idea to call it from a controller. Will have a go.